# Does ActiveRecord support dynamic conditions in sql statements?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord, conditional-statements

I want to make a SQL query in a Rails app that adds a condition when a drop-down menu is added. Obviously I don't want to search with a blank condition if the drop down is not selected. How can I develop a dynamic condition in an SQL statement?

untested example:

When dropdown is not selected: Object.find("billy," :conditions => {})

When dropdown is selected: Object.find("billy," :conditions => {"last_name => "johnson"})

Thank you for your input!

Comment: Quick note, Ruby itself doesn't do SQL, you're asking about Rails, ActiveRecord in specific :-)

Comment: If you are using ActiveRecord, Object is not a good name for a Model, since it is one of the core classes in Ruby.  If you're going for generic, try Model or Thing.  #2 - Thing.find("billy", :conditions => { etc.. } ) doesn't really work either. If you have somehow set up Thing to have an ID column with the value "billy", then you can say Thing.find("billy"), no need for conditions.  If you are using conditions, you usually want Thing.find :first, :conditions => { etc.. } or Thing.find :all, :conditions => { etc.. }.  Below you have some fine answers which will not run due to this issue.

Comment: @austinfromboston I agree, but I have a feeling he was just using that as an example, not actually using that class...at least, I hope he isn't using that class...

Answer (score 5):

Not quite sure what you are doing, but the general way to achieve this is to have the drop-down's value (not visible text) be the ID of the object you wish to select. If you don't have a selection then you can use something like this:

```
last_name = unless params[:object][:last_name]

conditions = []
conditions << "last_name = ?" unless last_name.blank?
conditions << last_name unless last_name.blank?

Object.find("billy", :conditions => conditions)
```

Check out [this link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002208) to learn more about `ActiveRecord::Base.find()` methods and the proper way to use them. Also look at [this great guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) to learn how to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks.

**Edit 1:** Modified code to be cleaner. This method also has the advantage of being able to easily add separate conditionals, just make sure that you add all of the "something = ?" before you add the associated value (param).

**Edit 2:** In case you haven't seen the [`select` form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001592), you might consider using it for your drop down. Makes life a lot easier :-)

Comment: I dunno if I stole "last_name => ?" from your code or adapted it from the question. Either way my proof-reading sucks! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Lol, we probably both looked at the original code...I hadn't even noticed it was wrong there too.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your #find is in a controller and that the value selected is coming in as an item in `params` (and I think you should consider changing things if not!) then you should be able to do something like this:

```
if params[:last_name] # or whatever it's actually called
  Object.find("billy," :conditions => {'last_name = ?', params[:last_name]})
else
  Object.find("billy")
end
```

If you're using a reasonably recent version of ActiveRecord (2.1 should do it, possibly 2.0) then you might shift that logic down to a `named_scope`:

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :for_last_name, lambda { |nm| { :conditions => nm.nil? ? {} : { last_name => nm } }
```

and then your controller boils down to (and we love thin controllers)

```
Object.for_last_name(params[:last_name])
```

(All somewhat untested)

Comment: He he, you must have looked at my code and used "last_name => ?" instead of "last_name = ?". Sorry to throw you off, I fixed mine :-)

Comment: Agreed on using named_scopes when attempting to handle dynamic conditions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
Object.find("billy", :conditions => last_name.nil? ? {} : {:last_name => last_name})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [SmartTuple](http://github.com/dadooda/smart_tuple) for that. It's simple, yet offers a systematic approach to building "conditional conditions".